# What is the main benefit and drawback of: GeoServer, MapServer, Mapnik?

Tags: qgis, geoserver, mapserver, mapnik

For the purpose of creating a comparison table, please recommend a couple of feature fields that would apply to each FOSS GIS server.  And, perhaps answer the question of which desktop GIS System, QGIS, ArcGIS, gvSIG it is best suited for migrating from, if applicable. Also, I hope to have field with skills required to set one up (for instance a specific programming language) if that's possible.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: This sounds like the sort of question everybody getting into web-mapping will (should?) ask.  As somebody who has used some but by no means all of these, I'd love to see a side-by-side comparison if anybody can give one!

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6604/comparison-of-the-different-open-source-gis-servers