# Feature table: Mapnik, GeoServer, CKAN, GeoNode, GeoNetwork?

Tags: geoserver, mapserver, geonode

I'm trying to get a clear view of the roles of different components here, this is not a "which is better" comparison, these components have different roles, but their functions overlap.

([Comparing different open source GIS servers?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6604/comparison-of-the-different-open-source-gis-servers) would be an answer if it included GeoNode, CKAN and Geonetwork, it links to this excellent table: http://www.geotests.net/cours/sigma/webmapping/2013/tableau6_webmapping2013.pdf)

So, can anyone help me fill in the holes / correct this table:

[image: image of table]
<sub>(source: [greygreen.org](http://greygreen.org/img/GeoGrid.png))</sub>
https://gist.github.com/tbnorth/3be5b91fe10243898017

Y = Yes, N = No, < = handled by included subcomponent

"Catalog data": provide searchable web / web-map front end view.

GeoNode and GeoNetwork use GeoServer for rendering and nominally WMS etc.

CKAN uses pycsw for metadata federation.

Comment: GeoServer -> Render tiles : Y

Comment: MapServer publish metadata :Y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For **GeoNetwork** :

- Render maps : N (instead of <)
- WMS : N (instead of <)
- WFS : N (instead of <)
- WFS-T : N (instead of <)
- Render tiles : N (instead of <)
- Catalog data : Y
- Publish metadata : Y
- Harvest metadata : Y

The "<" is not a clear answer for GeoNetwork. For example GeoNetwork and GeoServer are close but Geoserver is not a "subcomponent" of GeoNetwork.

Comment: thanks, will see what else comes in, stackexchange is not really set up for collaborative answering :-}

Answer (score 0):

GeoServer has a CSW plugin that can expose the basic metadata you've configured in your layer as dublin core and ISO records. But it's really basic, good enough if you have few layers, no need for extra info, and no need to just store records without data.