# Deciding which server best for geospatial data servicing?

Tags: raster, geoserver, vector, mapserver, software-recommendations

I want to serve both vector and raster data sets of large volume (ex: for a country).

Right now I'm using GeoServer for vector and MapServer for raster.

Is there any literature or reference such that which server is better for servicng vector data and raster datasets?

I got some reference from http://anitagraser.com/2010/06/08/geoserver-vs-mapserver/ and [Comparing different open source GIS servers?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6604/comparison-of-the-different-open-source-gis-servers).

Comment: Are you having an issue serving vector data from GeoServer?  Are you having an issue serving raster data from MapServer? If the answer to either is yes then you have the start of a more focussed and potentially new question for this site.

Comment: When you say you are using GeoServer for vector data, does that mean that the data source is vector data or the output data (for example through a WFS), the same question for MapServer (are you providing a WMS or WCS?) .  At work I use a variety of server software, deegree, mapserver, geoserver, arcgis and others; they all have their own issues and strengths; so you need to add to your question what your requirements (and restrictions) are, and that way you might get an answer on why one piece of software is better that fits your needs.